# how to run yadda BDD tests with jasmine

Tags: jasmine, bdd, jasmine-node

Is there any one who has an experience with these two frameworks ?

I saw in [yadda's home page](https://github.com/acuminous/yadda/tree/master/examples/jasmine) a jasmine section, but I've no clue how to run it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you use yadda with jasmine? I am curious about what part of jasmine was used. In the example I see a completely different assertion lib was used: assert.equal instead of expect(...).toEqual().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git clone http://github.com/acuminous/yadda
cd yadda
npm install
cd examples/jasmine
npm install
npm test
```

Answered in [yadda issue 39](https://github.com/acuminous/yadda/issues/39)